# How to solve intermittent crash that happens on device every 14 days?

Tags: swift

I'll try to be as clear and concise as possible, but it's not that easy. I've created an app that runs like it should both in simulator and on iPhone, but after some time testing it on my iPhone, the app crashes and I can't run it until it's rebuilt from Xcode. It doesn't help quitting the app either, it just shows the launchscreen, then it crashes and the home screen shows on iPhone. I've looked in the crashlog for the app in iPhone's settings --> privacy --> analysis, but nothing's there.

Since it doesn't help restarting the app, I assume it doesn't have something to do with a custom class or an array out of bounds, but rather something with the app delegate. Can someone guide me on the right track on how to narrow this down? Having an app with a bug is bad enough, but having it break completely and depend on a rebuild/re-install is worse :( (It's not on the app store, so it's no crisis yet)

Below is my AppDelegate.swift file. Dummy() is just a bunch of hardcoded appends to arrays, so I'll leave that out.

#### AppDelegate

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData
import SAPFiori
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        commonData.getAllCustomers()
        
        dummy.setUpProducts()
        dummy.setUpProductGroups()
        dummy.setUpStores()
        dummy.setUpStock()
        commonData.store = "7004"
        commonData.webStore = "7901"
        return true
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        /*
        The persistent container for the application. This implementation
        creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
        application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
        error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Paradigm_POS")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                
                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.orientationLock
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Have you tried to add an Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: "When I now have a built version on my iPhone that crashes - can I somehow run it in debug mode without building it again?" Yes. You can set Xcode to hook into the app at launch time, and launch it yourself, without using Xcode build or run, by tapping the springboard icon on the phone. If you have set up breakpoints, you will stop there. Note that `print` will not work so you should use `os_log` instead, and watch what happens in the mac Console application.

Comment: @matt: How do I tell Xcode to hook into? I've connected the phone by cable, chosen the iphone in the simulator menu and set exception breakpoint. When trying to launch the app on the iPhone, nothing happens..

Comment: @Magnas: There's no error messages shown :(

Comment: Build and run the app the first time to get it onto the phone. Now edit the scheme and change from Launch -> Automatically to Launch -> Wait for the executable. Close the editor, hit Run, and now launch the app manually from the phone. Xcode will hook in and breakpoints will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I finally found the issue and it was not related to code :) The reason for the crash was that I still was using an unpaid developer account, and with those - the app have to be re-built every 14 days.